# Populate a MVC WebGrid on DropDown select event using Jquery

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, dynamics-crm-2013

So I have done some research and googling on how to do this , but I have hit a roadblock and need assistance,I am having issues with populating a GridView(WebGrid MVC) with selected value of the DropDownList value.

I have managed to pass the controller data to the view, I am just struggling with populating the grid on the selection of the drop down list. When I include the grid in the view it populates it when the page renders, and I want it to populate only when drop down list value is selected. Please assist, I am fairly new to MVC

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        ProductPortalService.Service1Client client = new ProductPortalService.Service1Client();

        List<Top_100_Result> productType = client.GetTopProductsByTypeName();

        ViewBag.ProductType = new SelectList(productType.Select(x => x.Product_Type_Name).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));

        return View(productType);
    }


    public JsonResult ProductDescription(string ProductType)
    {
        ProductPortalService.Service1Client client = new ProductPortalService.Service1Client();

        List<Top_100_Result> productDesctriptionList = client.GetTopProductsByCategory(ProductType).Where(x => x.Product_Type_Name == ProductType).ToList();//new List<Top_100_Result>();

        var grid = new WebGrid(productDesctriptionList);
        var htmlString = grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "paramTable", htmlAttributes: new { id = "grid" }, columns: grid.Columns(
                                    grid.Column("Rank", "Rank"),
                                    grid.Column("Product_Number", "Product Number"),
                                    grid.Column("Product_Description", "Product Description"),
                                    grid.Column("Product Type_Name", "Product Type Name")));


        return Json(productDesctriptionList.Select(x => x.Product_Description)
                        , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your grid inside a partial view and call that partial view by dropdown ajax.
Use jquery like this:

```
$('#myDropDown').change( function() {

 /* Get the selected value of dropdownlist */
 var selectedID = $(this).val();

 /* Request the partial view with .get request. */
 $.get('/Controller/MyAction/' + selectedID , function(data) {

     /* data is the pure html returned from action method, load it to your page */
     $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
     /* little fade in effect */
     $('#partialPlaceHolder').fadeIn('fast');
 });
```

});

Comment: how do I go about doing that, I can create a partial view, struggling with the Jquery to populate the grid

Comment: Thanks Hadee, I figured it out, I put it inside a Partial view as you suggested, Thank you very much.